# Opening individual port works but not port range on FirewallD

Tags: rhel, firewalld

If I open an individual port on a zone using FirewallD and query the port it comes back with yes (allowed).

```
firewall-cmd --zone=zonename --add-port=6005/tcp
firewall-cmd --zone=zonename --query-port=6005/tcp
yes
```

If I open a port range and run a query on a port within that range, it comes back with no (blocked).

```
firewall-cmd --zone=zonename --add-port=6000-6010/tcp
firewall-cmd --zone=zonename --query-port=6005/tcp
no
```

Is this normal behaviour or am I not doing something correctly? (These rules are also added using --permanent and I do issue a reload after each change).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From RHEL support, this is by design. You need to query the whole port range to get "yes". Querying for individual ports within the range is not supported.

Comment: because it is how the rules in iptables look like ...

Comment: @Jakuje yeah I didn't know this. I had another support question open and asked about this too. I thought it actually probed the firewall and not just looked at the rules. If you have complicated setups it would be nice for it to tell you yes that port is open under the range x-y.

Comment: Sure. But underlying mechanism under `firewalld` is `iptables`, which is based on such rules. Though, good you resolved your case.

Comment: @Jakuje That's why I was confused... where were you 2 weeks ago when I posted the question? lol

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have notification for all the tags (already follow a lot of the). Next time :P